# Most Efficient Way To Filter Revisioned Order Numbers

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I have an issue with filtering out orders in my T-SQL database, we use the format "Q123456" to assign an order number, and this is appended with "-X" (X being the revision number).  I need to eliminate all of the older revisions (and the original without the "-X") if a newer one is present.

I know that I can use wildcard characters for this, and check the strings against each other, but all of my answers seem extremely inefficient running a ridiculous number of comparisons.  The run time gets out of control, very quickly and I imagine there is a much better structure to utilize.

Thank you in advance, if you need anymore information let me know and I'll do my best to provide it.

EDIT: Example data, you have orders: 
Q123456
Q123456-1
Q123456-2
Q134567

I need to remove Q123456 and Q123456-1 from the results of the queue, because of the presence of Q123456-2.  Q124567 will also be a result as it is the most up to date entry for that order.

Comment: sample data and the expected output would help.

Comment: Add some sample table before and after versions - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can assume:

- All orders are 7 characters in length except when they have a revision....
- no revision exceeds '-9' and if it does all orders are displayed as -xx with leading zero (-01...-10): If not we have to do some more work.  Like take the right most part of the order to the - and then cast it to integer and order by it and assign 0 when no - exists.
- Order_Num is the "ORDER_NUMBER in your table.

We can use a window function and a common table expression to generate a row number for each order_Number series (Q123456 of Q123456,Q123456-1) and then only select the one with the highest order_number (ordered by order num desc)

```
With CTE AS (SELECT A.*, Row_number() over (PARTITION BY  substring(Order_Num,1,7) 
                                            ORDER BY order_num Desc) RN
             FROM table)
Select * from cte where RN = 1
```

Without a cte...

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT A.*, Row_number() over (PARTITION BY  substring(Order_Num,1,7) 
                                     ORDER BY order_num Desc) RN
      FROM table)
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: That seems perfect, should fit into my CTE without any difficulty.  Thank you, very much.  You've saved me from a big headache, much more efficient than comparing everything against everything.

Comment: if performance is a problem you could add a computed column in the table so the order_Num 1,7 is always already separated out already thus negating the run time calculation at a cost on time at update.